# Why is the direct substitution property so specific

Tags: calculus, limits, definition

Mt text book states the Direct Substitution Property as

If *f* is a polynomial or a rational function and *a* is in the domain, then 
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)
\end{align*}$$
Why does this definition not include radical functions?

Comment: If by radical functions you mean square roots, it has mostly to do with the branch cut in the complex plane, so that in its super-full-generality a square root is generally not considered a continuous functions unlinke the polynomials and rational functions (although you need to be careful with rational functions, ensure the denominator is non-zero where you compute the limit).

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva But wouldn't the property work for radical functions? If it wouldn't, would you give me an example?

Comment: You got your answer below.

Comment: @TAAPSogeking : you're right, this Property _should_ include radical functions.  In fact, almost _any_ function you are likely to encounter in a calculus class, such as algebraic functions, exponential, trigonometric, logarithmic functons, and products, sums, differences, and quotients thereof, will be continuous on its entire domain.  Some calculus books explain this poorly.  The most familiar named non-continuous function is the floor function or greatest integer function $\lfloor x \rfloor$, but it's more of a computer science function than a calculus function.

Comment: @TAAPSogeking : since you used the letter $x$ rather than $z$, I'll ignore the issue of square roots and such in the complex plane that Patrick mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, that's a theorem, not a definition. (It's not *defining* the limit, just stating that it has a certain value under those hypotheses.)

Anyway, it's true in much more generality: If $f$ is any [continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) on the real numbers (or a subset of the real numbers), then for all $a$ in the domain of $f$,
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a).$$
The converse is also true: if a function $f$ satisfies the above condition, then it is continuous.

So, what that theorem in your book really means is that polynomials and rational functions are continuous on their domain. (Rational functions may have poles at which the function isn't defined, but those aren't in the domain, so the function is still continuous.)

I don't know why your book states it like that; it seems very misleading, since it suggests (incorrectly) that those types of functions are the *only* ones with that property.

Also, if by "radical function", you're just talking about the non-negative real-valued $n$-th root, then it is indeed continuous as a function from $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ to $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, where $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ denotes the set of non-negative real numbers. (If you want to consider the full, complex-valued $n$-th root function, on the other hand, things get more complicated with [multivalued functions and branch cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point), but that's probably beyond the scope of your course.)

Comment: Stewart's book contains a statement like the one the OP cites (maybe the OP is using Stewart).  Is it indeed misleading and I have to improve it when I teach calculus.  The book is in its 7th edition and this turkey is still in there.